# Ruby on Rails vs ASP.NET MVC 3 for a .NET Guy?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3

I am very new to RoR and I want to select between ASP.NET MVC3 and RoR. C# is sure easier for me as I have been doing it for so long but I am wondering if there is any point to consider using RoR over ASP.NET MVC to develop a real world website?

What else do I get with RoR which I can't get with ASP.NET MVC 3 that worth spending the time to master RoR? I though the available community RoR plug-in would be one reason but it does not seem that organized and seems like the learning curve to do the right things is going to be so big that it won't practically save much time for a newby! I could be wrong here and I really appreciate your real-life comment on this? Mind you that I still have to learn ASP.NET MVC but that sounds quick for a .NET Guy!

What could RoR offer to a .NET guy that **WORTH** picking RoR over ASP.NET MVC 3? and please the practical advices! :)

Comment: How is this question off topic or not a real question? Any way, I have added the `advice` tag on the question.

Comment: @zabba, why? Looks like a non-tag to me.

Comment: @bzlm, what's a non-tag?

Comment: @zabba only 95 questions, no wiki summary, unclear purpose (questions requiring "advice" are usually not answerable, and hence not welcome according to the site charter), etc. :)

Comment: Chill guys! How is "what are values of RoR over .NET MVC for a NET dev?" not a question?!!!Not locked on MVC at all and was just wondering the answer!!

Comment: @Mike, this question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: I could read but this this question DOES NOT solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion! :)

Comment: Lol @ apneadiving, Davy8, bzlm, David Glenn, bmargulies for closing this question

Comment: To all who follow: this question is off topic because it's mostly opinionated answers and not really that useful -- there is no "right" answer -- albeit it still is popular, and many of us (including myself) have exactly this question. It's just a poor fit to the Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

They are both fantastic, and can accomplish the same goals very quickly.  I used a great book to learn a while back, and it would be right up your alley: [Rails for .Net Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356204)

Also, I wrote a post about [going from MVC to RoR](http://naspinski.net/post/Learning-Ruby-on-Rails-for-a-Net-MVC-C-Coder.aspx) a while back as well.

As for comparisons, they both have strengths as has been covered, but here are a few that stick out to me:

- I really do like RoR's deployment and simple ways to push to live sites - no scripts to run at all, just a bit of command line should get you up and running once the code is actually written. If you choose RoR, **UNDERSTAND THE COMMAND LINE COMMANDS - it will make your life so much easier!**
- As you mentioned, the plugins are great, and can really be used to speed things up.
- As a .Net dev, MVC will be a breeze, I would recommend using Razor, as it is very simple and less cluttered than the old 2.0 non-razor rendering.
- .Net's EF4 can be compared almost directly to RoR's ActiveRecord, great ORM systems tfor dealing with data.
- I have found that .Net's documentation is a bit more consistent and thorough.
- One problem I had with RoR was the rapid and drastic changes; not so long ago, they upgraded to 3.0 on my host, and I did not lock my version - all sorts of stuff broke until I figured out the new stuff (I should have frozen my version).

It is not a clean cut choice - both are great.  As you are already a .Net dev, I would guess MVC3 would be the way to go, but both are easy to learn.

Comment: Now that ASP.NET MVC is open source, I wonder how quickly it will close the feature gap with RoR. I'm putting my money on MVC3 now that the developer community will have the ability to contribute to a product that is still supported in full by the MS engineering teams.

Comment: Not sure about RoR. If you are a.NET guy with C# MVC and Razor, but you find MS MVC, WebAPI, WCF, EF a bit cumbersome, and want a tighter packed solution... you can try SS http://www.servicestack.net/ ... It is free, open source, very active community supports .net and mono, full replacement of the above heavy framworks. I personally heart it a lot :)

Comment: Ruby versioning is simple and predictable if you use Bundler, as you should be.

Answer (score 31):

I use and like both, and the problem with a question like this is that they're so different that you could go on all day about apples vs. oranges, but since your question is pretty non-specific, I'll just say:

If you consider yourself "a .NET guy," then you *should* learn a language which works very differently than C#, and a dynamic language like Ruby isn't a bad place to start. (Another option would be a functional language like Haskell, Scala, etc.)

You will be a better programmer after you do, and you won't have to call yourself "a .NET guy" anymore!

Comment: I agree but my goal in to have a real web site up and running as fast as possible and extending my horizons is not my main goal right now. I sure do value learning new great things like Ruby but my focus right now is to pick the right option for limited time that I have. And why are the apples and oranges where their goal is to be a web development framework?

Comment: Getting a real site running quickly will not be a problem with Rails. Do yourself a favor: Spend a week working through [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) before you decide it will hurt your time to market. Only risk is that you'll learn something! The reason they're "apples and oranges" is that they work differently, run on different platforms, etc. They have MVC architecture in common, and there's clearly a lot of influence -- mostly in one direction -- but they're very different worlds. It can be a mind-expanding difference.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll do so. Would you please still comment what one could get with Rails which is available in .MVC from practical perspective given that you have used both?

Answer (score 6):

Not a RoR dev here, but I do Django and I think the same question could be asked for Django as well.  The #1 thing that I like Django over ASP.NET MVC is that Django comes with the ORM already.  Which means most any code examples you'll find on the web will kind of follow a similar pattern.  With ASP.NET MVC you can pick from lots of different ORMs which can be a good thing, but can also cause confusion.

Just like @Craig said though, it really is apples vs oranges.  I'd pick ASP.NET MVC if I was required to deploy it on a MS stack, and use Django for "personal" projects or projects that required it on to be deployed on linux.

Comment: Never used Django before.  I'm a Rails and .NET MVC guy.  Almost every .NET MVC tutorial that I have seen assumes that you are using Entity Framework and the documentation and tutorials on the ASP.NET site are very good.  To include EF in a MVC project you simply type a command into the NuGet package manager console - just like getting a gem with Rails except  you are getting a .net assembly reference.  IMHO .NET MVC with EF and Code First along with AppHarbor for deployment are the closest you can get to a Rails environment.

Answer (score 6):

You mention in your response to craig Stuntz that you want the 'right option for the limited time you have'

Go with mvc3 and focus on learning just that, instead of a new language and framework at the same time.  RoR is great, but its a new language, framework and IDE all at once and chances are you wont get it right first time.  I didnt.

There are some really good tutorials on [the asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc) that will get you up and running very quickly

Comment: That has been my thinking too and but I hear people are talking about how easy it is to do things in RoR even for newbies but I am wondering if that is for a hello world web site or a real-world production website. I know my question is tricky but something tells me RoR is a new language, framework and IDE all at once as you mentioned and it can not be as fast of doing a production product with .MVC but I wanted to know what is the .net community experiences with this? I mostly want to know, beside the fun, what is the point of choosing RoR over .MVC3? Thanks